# Change SPAN class with any animation

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have two dimensional array in my controller which I display using this code:

```
<div class="line" 
    ng-repeat="line in grid.cells track by $index">

    <span class="cell" 
         ng-class="{c0:(cell==0),c2:(cell==2),c4:(cell==4),c8:(cell==8),c16:(cell==16),c32:(cell==32),c64:(cell==64),c128:(cell==128),c256:(cell==256),c512:(cell==512)}"
         ng-repeat="cell in line track by $index">

        {{ display_value(cell); }}

    </span>
</div>
```

Here I am changing class of SPAN using ng-class.

Here is a part of CSS:

```
span.c0 {
  background-color: #ccc0b3;
  color: #776e65;
}

span.c2 {
  background-color: #eee4da;
  color: #776e65;
}
```

User press the button and change the array in the Controller and View is updated automatically:  cell value change -> span class change -> color of SPAN change.  But this changes are very quickly

How can I use some animation to slow the change in this case?  For example, something like this: http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/ .  Or some fade-in, fade-out effects.  Do I need to use angular's directives or it is the matter of CSS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you right, you will just need css transitions for this.

Here is some example css:

```
.item 
{
    transition-property: background-color;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.item.c1
{
    background-color: green;
}

.item.c2
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Such HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="item c1"></div>
    <div class="item c1"></div>
    <div class="item c1"></div>
    <div class="item c1"></div>
</div>
```

Here is just some sample js to toggle the class change

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".row .item");

setInterval(function(){
    for(var a=0; a<elements.length; a++){
        elements[a].classList.toggle("c1");
        elements[a].classList.toggle("c2");
    }
}, 2500);
```

### And here is a jsFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ychk4g7h/

Comment: I am using AngularJS. AngularJS set the class of element and 'transition-property' doesn't work in my example

Comment: @demas are you changing the elements via ajax or do the shell of the "items" remain and you just change it's classes + inner html? It really should work, check this easy demo with plain  css: http://jsfiddle.net/ychk4g7h/1/ . It's perfect when angular is just changing classes, this is what you need. Maybe post the css you tried here.

Comment: Here is a full example: https://github.com/demas/ang_test. Here I am change items values https://github.com/demas/ang_test/blob/master/js/script.js and Angular set the classes themself

Comment: can you build a demo with this? When angular is changeing classes it's liekely the css is wrong. It's important to define the transition for the item like `span` and **not** in `span.c1` and `span.c2`

Comment: Thanks, it is works. Simple example is working perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/demas/zhesrvqz/5/.